# Create a dummy based on variables ranking

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataset below with columns HHID to hum_aid and would like to create the column `desired` based on the condition that the columns remittances, govt_aid and hum_aid are the top 2 ranked i.e the top 2 should be at least one of the 3, as in the following dataframe:

```
df <- structure(list(HHID = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13), 
                     empl = c(1000, 1750, 480, 630, 1200, 1000, 1700, 500, 300, 0, 400, 900, NA),
                     agric = c(750, 650, 400, 400, 0, 750, 0, 0, 750, 0, 300, 900, NA),
                     loans = c(0, 350, 300, 0, 0, 1200, 500, 250, 500, 0, 700, 0, NA),
                     assets = c(500, 0, 0, 0, 700, 0, 0, 500, 150, 0, 500, 750, NA),
                     remittances = c(0, 200, 1500, 1250, 0, 500, 700, 900, 1200, 0, 1000, 0, NA),
                     govt_aid = c(0, 0, 1200, 1000, 0, 0, 0, 900, 1300, 0, 800, 0, NA),
                     hum_aid = c(0, 0, 800, 1200, 0, 0, NA, 1400, 1500, 0, 200, 1100, NA),
                     desired = c(0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, NA)), 
                class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -13L))
```

PS: I would appreciate a solution that doesn't involve reshaping.
Thanks in advance!

Edit:
I realized my original dataset didn't capture extreme cases such as all variables having value 0 or NA or two or one of the interested variables being in the top 3 ranks. IDs 10-13 capture these cases.

Comment: did you want the top two to contain at least two of those three, or at least one of the three?

Answer (score 1):

A base R version:

```
checked_cols = c("remittances", "govt_aid", "hum_aid")
topn = 2

df$d <- apply(df, 1, \(x) !length(setdiff(sort(x, T)[seq_len(topn)], x[checked_cols])))
```

Or a rowwise dplyr version:

```
df |>
  # for each row,
  rowwise() |>
  # check if remittances, government aid or humanitarian aid is equal to the top two values. If in more than one column, the answer is yes, then TRUE
  mutate(d = sum(map_lgl(c(remittances, govt_aid, hum_aid), ~ .x %in% tail(sort(c_across(empl:hum_aid)), 2))) > 1) |>
  ungroup()
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 9 × 10
   HHID  empl agric remittances govt_aid loans assets hum_aid desired d    
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>       <dbl>    <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl> <lgl>
1     1  1000   750           0        0     0    500       0       0 FALSE
2     2  1750   650         200        0   350      0       0       0 FALSE
3     3   480   400        1500     1200   300      0     800       1 TRUE 
4     4   630   400        1250     1000     0      0    1200       1 TRUE 
5     5  1200     0           0        0     0    700       0       0 FALSE
6     6  1000   750         500        0  1200      0       0       0 FALSE
7     7  1700     0         700        0   500      0      NA       0 FALSE
8     8   500     0         900      900   250    500    1400       1 TRUE 
9     9   300   750        1200     1300   500    150    1500       1 TRUE
```

Answer (score 1):

A solution that calcs all rows at once. I'm assuming that you want `desired=1` if *any* of the mentioned columns are ranked 1-2.

```r
library(dplyr)
ranks <- df |>
  transmute(across(c(remittances, govt_aid, hum_aid),
                   ~ rank(-.x, ties.method = "min") <= 2)) |>
  rowSums()
df |>
  mutate(
    desired2 = if_else(is.na(remittances) & is.na(govt_aid) & is.na(hum_aid),
                       NA, +(ranks > 0))
  )
> 
# # A tibble: 13 × 10
#     HHID  empl agric loans assets remittances govt_aid hum_aid desired desired2
#    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>       <dbl>    <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>    <int>
#  1     1  1000   750     0    500           0        0       0       0        0
#  2     2  1750   650   350      0         200        0       0       0        0
#  3     3   480   400   300      0        1500     1200     800       1        1
#  4     4   630   400     0      0        1250     1000    1200       1        1
#  5     5  1200     0     0    700           0        0       0       0        0
#  6     6  1000   750  1200      0         500        0       0       0        0
#  7     7  1700     0   500      0         700        0      NA       0        0
#  8     8   500     0   250    500         900      900    1400       1        1
#  9     9   300   750   500    150        1200     1300    1500       1        1
# 10    10     0     0     0      0           0        0       0       0        0
# 11    11   400   300   700    500        1000      800     200       0        0
# 12    12   900   900     0    750           0        0    1100       0        0
# 13    13    NA    NA    NA     NA          NA       NA      NA      NA       NA
```

Edited to handle the row with `NA`s.

Comment: thanks so much for taking time and helping me. I need some help in ensuring that if all the variables have ```NA``` that the new variable also has ```NA```

Comment: thanks so much for the additional help. I sincerely appreciate

Answer (score 1):

One approach in `dplyr` (here I made `desire2` just to check, but could overwrite `desired` if you wanted)

```
df %>% 
  mutate(across(c(remittances, govt_aid, hum_aid), 
                ~ .x %in% rev(sort(.x))[1:2], .names = "{.col}_T2")) %>%
  mutate(desire2 = +(any(remittances_T2, govt_aid_T2, hum_aid_T2)), .by = HHID) %>%
  select(-contains("T2"))

  HHID  empl agric remittances govt_aid loans assets hum_aid desired desire2
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>       <dbl>    <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <int>
1     1  1000   750           0        0     0    500       0       0       0
2     2  1750   650         200        0   350      0       0       0       0
3     3   480   400        1500     1200   300      0     800       1       1
4     4   630   400        1250     1000     0      0    1200       1       1
5     5  1200     0           0        0     0    700       0       0       0
6     6  1000   750         500        0  1200      0       0       0       0
7     7  1700     0         700        0   500      0      NA       0       0
8     8   500     0         900      900   250    500    1400       1       1
9     9   300   750        1200     1300   500    150    1500       1       1
```

Comment: thanks so much for taking time and helping me. I need some help in ensuring that if all the variables have ```NA``` that the new variable also has ```NA```

Answer (score 1):

Base R:

```
cols <- c("remittances", "govt_aid", "hum_aid")
df$desired <- as.integer(
  Reduce("+", lapply(cols, \(x) rank(-df[[x]], ties.method="min") <= 2L)) > 0
)
```